# Firebird sql select multiple rows

Tags: sql, select, pivot, rows, firebird

I have a table in Firebird 2.5 like

```
Point   X    Y     Z 
 1     100   100  50
 2     110  120   50.34
 3     145  155   56
```

How can I make a select query to select point 1 and point 3  with result

```
point1   P1X  P1Y  P1Y point2  P2X  P2Y   P2Z
  1      100  100  50  3      145    155  56
```

Comment: Do you think, the output you provided would be user friendly to read?

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: What are the rules for this pivot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you *really* want to do is a bit unclear.  The following returns the desired results:

```
select min(point) as point1, min(x) as p1x, min(y) as p1y, min(z) as p1z,
       max(point) as point2, max(x) as p2x, max(y) as p2y, max(z) as p2z
from t;
```

Alternatively, you might want:

```
select p1.*, p2.*
from t p1 join
     t p2
     on p1.point = 1 and p2.point = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is to join 2 records in one new record and the sql select p1.*  etc is exactly the solution .